# Upload multiple images with carrierwave to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, image-uploading, liquid

I have newsletter creator, which has couple of section types (`"text"` or `"image"`) defined in hash (like `{"section1" => "text", "section2" => "image", "section3" => "image"}` - it depends of earlier-choosen `newsletter_template`.

By liquid help I'm iterating throught this hash and display proper form (text_field or file) - I want images to be like attachable, but how do this to work properly? (e.g. upload file, give it dependency: destroy, but save to hash only link to the image (like: `"section2" => "http://mysite.com/images/image1.jpg"`)